# Display dynamic content in a fancybox modal using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am building an actors directory that pulls their details from an external directory site and populates a modal popup linked to their picture.

Currently I have listed all the actors images, and when you click on them the modal popup (fancybox) appears.

Tp pull the actor info from their external directory, I am using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) - this allows me to target elements on their external page and echo them on my page.

What I can't figure out how to do is have the modal populate dynamically depending on the actor that is clicked. Right now, when you click on any actor, it populates with just the first actors page. I need a way to make this dynamic and need to avoid heavy load times so ideally using AJAX.

Here is the code that handles the content for the modal:

```
function actor_content() {

    echo '<div class="hidden" style="display:none">';
    echo '<div id="nial_actor_content">';
        // Create DOM from URL or file
        $html = file_get_html('http://www.spotlight.com/5094-1276-6177');

        // Find all images 
        foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
               echo '<img src="http://www.spotlight.com' . $element->src . '" /><br>';

        // Credits 
        echo $html->find('div.credits', 0); 

        // Skills 
        echo $html->find('div.skills', 0); 

        // Training
        echo $html->find('div.training', 0); 

    echo '</div>'; // #nial_actor_content
    echo '</div>'; // hidden container


}
```

I am using wordpress, so when inside the loop I can get the unique url for each actor by using:

```
$spotlight_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_spotlight_url', true);
echo $spotlight_url;
```

For fancybox I am just using inline content:

```
echo '<a href="#nial_actor_content" class="actor_lightbox nial_actor">';
...
echo '</a>';
```

and the jQuery for this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".nial_actor").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
});
});
```

What I am trying to do now is dynamically populate each modal popup, but using AJAX so I'm not loading 100s of profiles on page load.

**UPDATE:**
Ive changed my approach slightly now, The external URL has a unique ID in it for each profile. So I've stripped this ID like this:

```
$spotlight_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_spotlight_url', true); 
$spotlight_url_formatted = str_replace("http://www.spotlight.com/", "", $spotlight_url);
```

and then added that ID as the href attribute of the profile link (to call the fancybox modal). So now, my outputted html for my listed profiles looks like this:

```
<a href="#5094-1276-6177" class="actor_lightbox nial_actor"> 
    <img width="200" height="200" src="http://79.170.44.105/samskirrow.com/nial/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2016/06/yuri_buzzi.jpg" class="actor_image wp-post-image" alt="yuri_buzzi">
    <h3 class="actor_name">Yuri Buzzi</h3>
</a>

...
```

Then, for my inline content, I am using the same unique ID for the container, and then the content from the external site:

```
echo '<div class="hidden" style="display:none;">';
echo '<div id="'.$spotlight_url_formatted.'">';

        // Create DOM from URL or file
        $html = file_get_html($spotlight_url);
        // Credits 
        echo $html->find('div.credits', 0); 

echo '</div>'; // #nial_actor_content
echo '</div>'; // hidden container
```

This does work (in that when I click on an actor, their unique profile is shown in a modal). However, what my page is doing is loading ALL the profiles first and then displaying them, which is obviously going to take a long time to load when I have 100+ actors listed.

Is there a way to modify what I have done, but load all the info via AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Since you access your URLs with

```
 $spotlight_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_spotlight_url', true);
```

You can put each of those urls as an attribute to .nial_actor element like

```
   echo '<div id="nial_actor_content" myattr="$spotlight_url">';
```

and use the url like

```
$(".nial_actor").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    href: $(this).attr("myattr"),
    type: 'ajax'
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, how would I add the url to the actor_content() function?

Comment: This isn't working for me. I think the issue is that the content from $spotlight_url is from an external site - so we run into cross domain issues. Which is why I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to crawl the site for content. What I'm trying to avoid is loading each profile on the list page (as this will take a very long time to load) but to trigger the crawl for the external site linked to the profile when it is clicked

Comment: Follow this [link](http://zinoui.com/blog/cross-domain-ajax-request) to resolve cross-domain requests. You have to configure your php application so that it accepts client to send cross-domain requests.

Comment: I think we may be misunderstanding each other slightly. I don't have an issue with cross-domain requests, that is why I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). My issue is that all profile info for each actor in my list is being loaded at once, whereas I need to have it load when the modal is called - see my updated question